# Does adding Objective-C libraries to a Swift project increases app size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Currently I am working on a Swift project. I got a suggestion to remove Objective-C libraries as that decreases the app size. But I dont see any documentation on this. Could any one explain more?

Comment: library always take space, if you add anything to project it will increase project size.

Comment: Does adding swift library over objective c library makes any difference ?

Comment: not at all, check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Objective-C in a Swift app doesn't increase it's app size any more than it needs to.

As a matter of fact, Objective-C **libraries can significantly reduce your app size**, if they're **static libraries**. Static libraries get linked directly into your app without all metadata and unused symbols. Dynamic libraries are copied into the bundle along with all the symbols and all metadata, so they can take a lot of space. [Swift cannot be compiled into a static library as far as I know.](https://github.com/ksm/SwiftInFlux#static-libraries)

Objective-C is compiled and all dependencies it needs it has on the iOS device: all the dynamic libraries, it's runtime.

It's the opposite: adding Swift to your Objective-C project can increase the app's size, because it ships with Swift runtime library, because Swift's ABI is not stable yet.

[Adding Swift to project increase size substantiously. How and when can it be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275711/adding-swift-to-project-increase-size-substantiously-how-and-when-can-it-be-avo)